# Spring MVC unable to resolve view name

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am writing an application which I want to be able to package into a single executable Jar, and use an embedded web server to serve both a REST API and s set of configuration pages which consume the API (allowing the API to be accessed by other clients outside of the server e.g. an Android app).

So far I have a basic REST API working but keep having problems using it with a view, I have tried following the guide [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/) and have not been able to get the view name to resolve to the JSP page. Here are some log lines which seem to show it being unable to resolve it:

```
15:37:23.559 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /UserPage
15:37:23.560 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/UserPage]
15:37:23.561 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/UserPage] are [/**]
15:37:23.561 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/UserPage] are {}
15:37:23.562 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/UserPage] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@37f9ecb0] and 1 interceptor
15:37:23.563 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/UserPage] is: -1
15:37:23.564 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [UserPage] against base location: ServletContext resource [/]
15:37:23.564 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [UserPage] against base location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
15:37:23.565 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [UserPage] against base location: class path resource [resources/]
15:37:23.565 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [UserPage] against base location: class path resource [static/]
15:37:23.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Trying relative path [UserPage] against base location: class path resource [public/]
15:37:23.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
```

I have a feeling that because I am trying to run this with an embedded Tomcat server (as opposed to deploying it to a Tomcat server) I am missing a step which configures the `/webapp/` directory as a webapp, but am fairly new to Spring so am unsure what I am missing.

src/main/webapp/web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>IeNoTenshi</display-name>
<description>IeNoTenshi internal webserver</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.dan_nixon.ienotenshi.web.service" /> 
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

src/com/dan_nixon/.../web/service/UsersController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class UsersController {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersController.class);
public static final int DEFAULT_COUNT = 10;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "test");
    model.addAttribute("name", "Test User");
    return "UserPage";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/user/{user_id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getUser(@PathVariable long user_id,
        Model model) {
    INTObjectDB db = new INTObjectDB();
    db.open();
    User user = db.getUser(user_id);
    user.getPermissions();
    db.close();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("UserPage");
    mav.addObject("username", user.getUsername());
    mav.addObject("name", user.getName());
    log.error(String.format("%s", mav));
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `@ResponseBody` in `getUser` method?

Comment: @PavelHoral That was from before I started trying to use views, removed it now.

Comment: What's the path of your jsp?

Comment: @Taylor ```src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/UserPage.jsp```

Comment: change your viewname to `"/UserPage"`

Comment: Log messages are not consistent with the code you have presented (view forward was to `/service/user/UserPage` which is not possible IMO), which makes me think that your project is in inconsistent state. Stop the server, clean your project, clean Tomcat as well and try it again.

Comment: @PavelHoral You were right, I did a clean build and the log messages no longer mention any redirection. I think that was from a previous failed attempt to get this working.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, I added the new log output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

With this error message

> 15:37:23.559 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
>   - Looking up handler method for path /UserPage

it seems you are trying to access something like

```
localhost:8080/yourApp/UserPage
```

but you obviously have no handler method mapped to that URL. What you have is a handler method mapped to `/service` that handles GET requests

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "test");
    model.addAttribute("name", "Test User");
    return "UserPage";
}
```

You should be sending the request to

```
localhost:8080/yourApp/service
```

Comment: The request that generated that log entry was for ```localhost:8080/service```.

Comment: @Dan Is there anything before the log that you posted?

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/HbdGLAT3) is everything from the end of the build tests to the server shutdown for the last run (the log currently in the question).

Comment: @Dan Your logs say otherwise. There's a handler for `/service` at line 1047, but nothing about handling a request to `/service`.

Comment: Hmm, that may have been the wrong log, [this](http://pastebin.com/FWZzMHX5) is certainly form a request to ```/service```

Comment: @Dan Try this to start. Right now your `ContextLoaderListener` is meaningless. Remove it and the `<contet-param>` element. I think there might be some conflicting beans. And add an `<init-param>` for the `DispatcherServlet` pointing its `contextConfigLocation` to your context file.

Comment: @Dan Also, in the XML you've shown us, you don't declare the `mvc` namespace. Can you please review what you're showing us and update it with the real code and configuration.